# Only one option from mySQL query not showing

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get all the sub-menu items to show on the "New Motorcycles" section on http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2. For example, Adventure should have three options coming off, not one. Here is the code I have used.

```
<?
$output = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM bikes, bikeTypes WHERE bikes.model_id = bikeTypes.model_id GROUP BY bikeTypes.model_id");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($output))
 {
   echo "<li><a href='test.php?id=" . $row['model_id'] . "'>".$row['model'].'</a><ul>';
   echo "<li><a href='details.php?id=" . $row['bike_id'] . "'>" . $row['bikeName'] . "</a></li>";
   echo '</ul>';   
   echo '</li>';
 }
//var_dump($result);
?>
```

Any ideas guys? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here is the structure of both tables from phpMyAdmin:

bikeTypes table:
[bike types table http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2/images/bikeTypesTable.jpg](http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2/images/bikeTypesTable.jpg)

bikes table:
[bikes table http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2/images/bikesTable.jpg](http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2/images/bikesTable.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> SELECT bikeTypes.id,bikeTypes.name,bikes.name,bikes.id FROM bikeTypes LEFT JOIN bikes ON
>   bikes.model_id = bikeTypes.model_id

If you see that the query I have written has a `LEFT JOIN` in it.What are you doing is treated as an `INNER JOIN` by the DB engine.

But the thing you need here is

```
 $output = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM bikeTypes");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($output))
     {

       echo "<li><a href='test.php?id=" . $row['model_id'] . "'>".$row['model'].'</a><ul>';
       $subcat = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM bikes WHERE model_id = $row['model_id']");

       while($rowSub = mysqli_fetch_array($subcat)){    
       echo "<li><a href='details.php?id=" . $rowSub['bike_id'] . "'>" . $rowSub['bikeName'] . "</a></li>";
       }
       echo '</ul>';   
       echo '</li>';

 }
```

Just see where you want to close ul and li.

Comment: What have you changed? What is the difference? Why would this work and his won't? Please add those points instead of just throwing code at him.

Comment: If you see that the query I have written has a LEFT JOIN in it.What are you doing is treated as an INNER JOIN by the DB engine.

Comment: Very good, this should be **part of the answer**, please include those details in the answer next time.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for the input, but that didn't work, and can't access the id's anymore. I have kept the original query, but god rid of "GROUP BY" and it has changed, as you can see on the website. What do you all think?

Comment: That is because you have used the query as I have posted.You should mention the fields in it using a table alias.Check the edits in answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Implemented that query, but still only coming up with one sub-category. Any other ideas?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to remove Group By.Try that also please.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that didn't work either unfortunately. You can see the results on the website concerned.

Comment: Can you post the structure of both the tables in your question please?

Comment: Hey there! Edits attached to main question. Thanks!

Comment: test.php link is of category and details.php is of sub category?Right?

Comment: Yes that is right, and they are both working fine, verified that. It is just the menu sorting that is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19014/discussion-between-techie-28-and-matt-maclennan)